# How can I ignore some unit-tests without lowering the code-coverage percentage?

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, code-coverage

I have one class which talks to DataBase.

I have my integration-tests which talks to Db and asserts relevant changes. But I want those tests to be ignored when I commit my code because I do not want them to be called automatically later on.
(Just for development time I use them for now)

When I put [Ignore] attribute they are not called but code-coverage reduces dramatically.

> Is there a way to keep those tests but not have them run automatically
>   on the build machine in a way that the fact that they are ignored does
>   not influence code-coverage percentage?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whatever code coverage tool you use most likely has some kind of CoverageIgnoreAttribute or something along those lines (at least the ones I've used do) so you just place that on the method block that gets called from those unit tests and you should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

What you request seems not to make sense. Code-Coverage is measured by executing your tests and log which statements/conditions etc. are executed. If you disable your tests, nothing get executed and your code-coverage goes down.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know if this is applicable to your situation. But spontaneously I am thinking of a setup where you have two solution files (.sln), one with unit/integration tests and one without. The two solutions share the same code and project files with the exception that your development/testing solution includes your unit tests (which are built and run at compile time), and the other solution doesn't. Both solutions should be under source control but only the one without unit tests are built by the build server.

This kind of setup should not need you to change existing code (too much). Which I would prefer over rewriting code to fit your test setup.

Answer (score 0):

TestNG has groups so you can specify to only run some groups, automatically and have the others for usage outside of that. You didn't specify your unit testing framework but it might have something similar.

Comment: How this relates to calculation of a code covergate for the not runned tests?

Comment: He doesn't want them called when he commits but he still wants them counted. This prevents them from being called, but they are not ignored so they will still count towards code coverage. It is a silly workaround but accomplishes what I think he wants.

Comment: are you sure that in this way code coverage would not be changed as well? (You mean that tests will be counted basically as tests count or in tyrms of code coverage?)

Comment: It depends on the code coverage tool, if you can tell it to count coverage for tests from all groups but tell it to run only those from some groups then it will do what he is trying to accomplish.